# Replace charset at specific position in line of file

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a file thats loaded with my program, what i need to do is for example:

[BEFORE]

```
1111111111     2222222222       3333    30
1111111111     2222222222       3333    20
1111111111     2222222222       3333    10
1111111111     2222222222       3333   150
1111111111     2222222222       3333   260
1111111111     2222222222       3333   370
```

[AFTER]

```
1111111111     2222222222       3333    30
1111111111     2222222222       3333    20
1111111111     2222222222       3333     9 <-- The change is here
1111111111     2222222222       3333   150
1111111111     2222222222       3333   260
1111111111     2222222222       3333   370
```

I have to replace last digits and save the file, that happens when I click the button.

The program finds the line requested, I'm using

```
string[] myString = File.ReadAllLines(@"fileLocation");
```

I guess I have to use `StreamReader` or something like that, this is pretty important to me because that file is a database for my program and values change all the time.

Well, when I click on the button, could some one help me?

Comment: I believe the easiest way to do this, would be to deserialize the line into the appropriate data structure, modify the value, then serialize it back to file.

Comment: You can use the `File.ReadAllLines` to read the lines, manipulate the desired line and change the array and then use `File.WriteAllLines` to write it back, all while using a lock. Give it a try and come back if no luck. Also, don't SHOUT, it's just annoying.

Comment: So you have to replace `9 #` with `10 #`? Is that the only change?

Comment: What is the size of your files are they small or big like 1GB? Are the files tabulated or spaced between one value and another?

Comment: I failed to solve this *find ten differences* puzzle...

Comment: @Tim Shmelter: not really, there is like 1k lines in that database and only numbers that change in whole document (by program) is the last 2 or 3 digits, that number represents ammount of *item* remaining in storage, so the changes can happen to any line.

Comment: You want to do database operations. So use a database.

Comment: Yes a better option would be for you to use SQLite or even SQL Compact which can be used without installation and would fit your needs without relying on a loose text file.

Comment: @Noloar & Shadow Wizard: I agree with you both but thats exactly what i don't know, how to change those numbers and save everything again...

Comment: hmmm... that database thing sounds complicated but i like chalenges... i saw MySQL being used in a similar program but when i saw what guy did to make it work i decided id go with a plain text. and i never used MySQL... :/ SQL compact sounds good, no installations. is it implemented in visual studio 2008 or do i have to download something from somewhere???

Comment: @MiodragVemic MySQL needs to be installed, SQLite you Only need the DLL referenced to your application to use it. SQL Compact comes with VS2008 I believe. [**Here is a simple kick start with SQLite**](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way i can think of.
you should split the values with something else than a random amount of spaces, as it is much easier to replace a value if the position can be defined statically.

So you have to know where to change the value
for an example

```
string[] myString = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation);

   string[] tmp = myString[2].split(' ');//spli each line on space
   tmp[tmp.length-1] = "9"; //This is where you change out the last number
   myString[a] = String.Join(" ", tmp); //join the new content on the line in the text

File.WriteAllLines(fileLocation, myString);//save everything again
```

Comment: split each line on space...hmmmm...ok that would save me alot of space and time.. theres a little catch though, this is a database of products in a market so it would go like this:
Coca Cola Light 2 liter [space(s)] 1234567890123 (barcode) 88.88 (price) 100 (ammount of  items left in storage)

Comment: if you have a database you whould definatly not do it this way. you whould want to run a SQL Update on the row in a column in a table. if you dont know how then you should google and read up on SQL and the insert and update command its as easy as the select statement you must have done to get the data.

Comment: and you cannot use file ReadAllLines on a database.

Comment: i knew id have to use SQL sometime... i have fobia of .NET framework and cluttered codes... thank you all, i'm going to google some SQL... or i could just make 4 different txt files and store every detail separately? jk... ;)

Comment: dont have a fobia for cluttered code, everyone have clutter code at some point. :P